# XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace Location

Tags: angularjs, xml, svg

```
Below is my svg code and I get the following error message on firefox browser:
```

XML Parsing Error: prefix not bound to a namespace
Location: http://localhost/spm_dev/material-design-iconsets/iconsets/action-icons.svg
Line Number 50, Column 84:

The icon shows up but click event listener on the icon is not working on firefox while it works on chrome and microsoft edge. Please I need your help. What am I doing wrong.

```
<g id="event_seat"><defs><path id="a" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"/></defs><clipPath id="b"><use xlink:href="#a" overflow="visible"/></clipPath><path d="M4 18v3h3v-3h10v3h3v-6H4zm15-8h3v3h-3zM2 10h3v3H2zm15 3H7V5c0-1.1.9-2 2-2h6c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2v8z" clip-path="url(#b)"/></g>
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal but complete sample allowing us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Okay, let me do that.

Comment: In general, if you serve SVG standalone as XML then you should make sure you declare any used namespaces i.g. the SVG namespace usually as a default namespace and the `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` if you use any of the attributes in the namespace SVG has borrowed.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Please where exactly should this be placed `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`. On the SVG file or on the html page

Comment: On the SVG file's root node.

Comment: Thanks guys...this helped solve my problem. Very grateful